# Simplification of $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Tags: derivatives

How can $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}$ be simplified, where $x$ is a function of $t$?

My guess is that since partial derivatives commute, that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}(1)=0$, but am not sure if I'm missing something.

Additionally would this mean that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx^2}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx^2}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}(2x)=2\dot{x}$?

Comment: $dx/dt=0$ already, if x is independent of t.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "solution," since no equation is present.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}$ would be the chain rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). Is $x$ a function of $t$ (i.e., as $t$ changes, does $x$ also change)? If $x$ doesn't depend on $t$, then the answer is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, yes. x is a function of t. And solution I suppose isn't the correct terminology here. A simplification of the expression, perhaps.

Comment: A solution requires an equation! Do you mean you want to find solutions to $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = 0$ ?

Comment: Maybe the OP means the second derivative? $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: No, sorry. I've edited the question to hopefully make it a little clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still unclear what you are asking. You don't need to concentrate on commuting partial derivatives (and they don't always commute!). As written, $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}$ which doesn't seem helpful. Do you need to solve some sort of equation?

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is asking like this is so unclear.  The question (as I understand it) is just asking "How do you find the derivative of velocity with respect to position?"

Comment: Yes, exactly. I should have presented my question that way originally, but your interpretation is correct. It was not a particularly well-posed question in the original post, so I'm glad you were able to decipher it :)

Comment: Don't confuse total derivatives with partial derivatives. Why do we type $\partial$ instead of $d$? Not for our health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x=f(t)$ gives the position of a particle at time $t$.  Then $\frac{dx}{dt} = f'(t)$ is the velocity of the particle at time $t$.  Let's write $v(t) = f'(t)$ for shorthand.

Your question is asking:  What's $\frac{dv}{dx}$?

Now the issue seems to be that $v$ does not *explicitly* depend on $x$ at all, which would seem to imply that $\frac{dv}{dx} = 0$.  This, however, oversimplifies the situation.

Am example might help:  Suppose we have a particle whose position is given by $x = t^2$ for $t\ge 0$.  Then $v = \frac{dx}{dt} = f'(t) = 2t$, which looks (as described above) like it doesn't depend on $x$.  But appearances can be deceiving!  In fact, the velocity *does* depend on position.  Just think about the moving object:  certainly, at different positions, the velocity will be different.  How do we reveal this in the equation of motion?

The key is that the formula $x = t^2$ does two things:  it *explicitly* defines the position as a function of time, but it also *implicitly* defines the time as a function of position.  That is, if we solve for $t$, we have $t = \sqrt{x}$ (remember, we are assuming $t \ge 0$).  Then substituting this into the velocity formula, we have

$$ v = 2\sqrt{x}$$

and then $\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Now let's step away from the specific example and go back to the general case.  We have
$$x = f(t)$$
whose derivative with respect to $t$ is
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = f'(t)$$
But also, inverting the original equation, we have
$$t = f^{-1}(x)$$
which, on substituting into the equation above, gives
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = f'(f^{-1}(x))$$
Now to take the derivative of this with respect to $x$, use the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = f''(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot (f^{-1})'(x)$$
Finally, use the Inverse Function Theorem, which says that $(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$, to conclude that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = f''(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

Going back to our example, we have $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x}$, $f'(t) = 2t$, and $f''(t) = 2$, so the formula above gives 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
as found above.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!